# Add Sidebar to Page

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

Right now I have a sidebar that only shows up on the Homepage, but I would like it to also show up on the "Contact Us" page (page ID - 13). I know I need to interject "if (is_page(13)) {"
within the code somehow but I can't seem to make it work. Here is the code as is:

```
function three_new_sidebars(){
if(is_front_page()){
?>
<div id="three-new-sidebars">
    <div id="three-new-sidebar-4">
        <ul class="sidebar_list">
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(is_front_page() || is_page('13')){
```

or, for an array of pages:

```
if(is_front_page() || is_page(array('13','14'))) {
```

For each, `||` is the "or" operator

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page